# In what year is The Art of Self-Defense set?

Tags: the-art-of-self-defense

*The Art of Self-Defense* seems to be set in a period before Internet usage became widespread. We see characters using a CRT monitor, a bulky camcorder, VHS tapes, buying and using audio CDs, and masturbating to photocopied adult magazines.

If I had to guess, I'd say early 90s, but it could also be early to late 80s, or maybe even late 90s to early 2000s. Hard to pin down based on the technology shown. I'm thinking maybe there was a hint to the exact date in the movie that I missed or maybe one of the people involved in the making of the movie talks about it.

Comment: I gave this an upvote, although others may vote to close this as trivia. I think it's an interesting and valid question that I'd like to see answered.